# Javascript getting an array from the index of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
var colors = ['blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'blue']
```

How would I get an array that tells me what position each of them is at? for example:

```
var reds = [1,2,3,5], blues = [0,4,6,7]
```

So far I have tried to use the `indexOf();` function but that will only return 1 of the values if there are multiple matches.

Comment: When go for loop, just check if red or blue then push to array of red , and blue, then you have red and blue index, is easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could collect all indices in an object with the color as property.

This approach features

- a classic [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) for iterating the index,
- a [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) to check the property and assign an array if not given,
- and [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), to get the index into the array with the color as name.

```js
const
    colors = ['blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'],
    indices = {};

for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    (indices[colors[i]] ??= []).push(i);
}

console.log(indices);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `forEach`, `for loop` to get the element and index and push it into respective array.

```js
var colors = ["blue", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "red", "blue", "blue"];

const reds = [];
const blues = [];

colors.forEach((color, index) => {
  if (color === "red") reds.push(index);
  else if (color === "blue") blues.push(index);
});

console.log(reds);
console.log(blues);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be easier to understand than the other answers:

```
var colors = ['blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'];

var reds = [];
var blues = [];

for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i)
{
    if(colors[i] == 'red')
    {
        reds.push(i);
    }
    else if(colors[i] == 'blue')
    {
        blues.push(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `reduce` to construct an object where the properties are your colors and the values an array with the indexes

```js
const colors = ['blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'];

const indices = colors.reduce((acc, color, index) => {
    return !acc[color] ? 
             { ...acc, [color]: [index]} :
             { ...acc, [color]: [...acc[color], index] }
}, {})

console.log(indices);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of [`Nina Scholz`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66843515/9071943) looks good. And I want to give another way to help you.

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to resolve it with the highest performance `O(n)` time complexity like below:

```js
const colors = ['blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'blue']

const result = colors.reduce((acc, color, index) => {
  acc[color] ??= [];
  acc[color].push(index);
  
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I've just added an answer to help you. Pls, take a look at ^^! @lmg1114

Answer (score -1):

```
let arr1 = ['blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'];

const redElements = arr1.filter(x => x == 'red');

const blueElements = arr1.filter(x => x == 'blue');
```

Filter returns an array;